# Input Data Validator (good practice)

Tags: c#, unit-testing, validation

I work at an application that receives data from user and I try to write a validator function for it, but I'm not sure if this is the correct way to proceed.

Example: The user will input a number (as string, don't ask why I don't use an int, let it be a string), let's say "103", and I'will use this number inside a function, but first, at the beginning of that function I call a validator function:

```
private bool ValidateCommandCode(string code)
{
    bool isValid = false;

    byte commandByte = new byte();

    if (byte.TryParse(code, out commandByte))
    {
        isValid = true;
    }
    else
    {
        Log.Error($"Command number {CommandCode} for the request is not valid!");
        isValid = false;
    }

    return isValid;
}

private async void MainFunction()
{
    if (ValidateCommandCode(CommandCode) == false)
        return;

    // ... do the magic with the CommandCode ...

}
```

in the same manner, I want to validate another field filled by the user:
e.g of data: 000A000B

```
private bool ValidateRequestData(string data)
        {
            bool isValid = false;
            
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Payload) && !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Payload))
            {
                if (Payload.Trim().Replace(" ", "").Length % 2 != 0)
                {
                    Log.Error($"Payload (Data) {Payload} for the request doesn't have an even number of bytes!");
                    isValid = false;

                }
                else
                {
                    isValid = true;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                isValid = true;
            }

            return isValid;
        }
```

Is this a good way to proceed? Aren't so many flags "isValid" too confusing?

Comment: This question might fit better on the [codereview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) site.

Comment: Set the IsValid default to true and you will see how you don't need all those elses

Comment: I've posted to code review, if anyone needs the link: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/265770/input-data-validator-good-practice

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this question belongs to codereview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create a separate class for validation and decouple logging by passing a logger to the validator.

```cs
    public interface ILogger
    {
        void Error(string message);
    }
    public class Logger : ILogger
    {
        public void Error(string message) { }
    }

    public class LoggingValidator
    {
        private readonly ILogger _logger;
        // Payload looks like a hex number, so we check this.
        private static readonly Regex _payloadExp = new Regex(@"^\s*([0-9A-F]{2} *)+\s*$", RegexOptions.Compiled);
        public LoggingValidator(ILogger logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }


        public bool CheckCommand(string value)
        {
            if (byte.TryParse(value, out _))  // Discard operator _
                return true;
            _logger.Error("Your message.");
            return false;
        }

        public bool CheckPayload(string value)
        {
            if (_payloadExp.IsMatch(value ?? ""))
                return true;
            _logger.Error("Your message.");
            return false;
        }
    }

    public class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var validator = new LoggingValidator(new Logger());
            string value = "123";
            if (validator.CheckCommand(value)) { /* ... */ }
            if (validator.CheckPayload(value)) { /* ... */ }
        }
    }
```